# dojo: inheritance with default value - the mixin doesn't happen

Tags: inheritance, constructor, dojo, mixins, declare

I wish to declare a new dojo class inheriting from an existing dojo class, but with my own choice of default values for the class's properties.  (The user can still override those values.)

I am declaring my own version of the `dijit.form.FilteringSelect` such that:

- the `hasDownArrow` property defaults to `false` (rather than the standard `true`) and
- there's an extra possible property `storeUrl` which allows me to connect the `FilteringSelect` to the corresponding `QueryReadStore`.

Here's what I did, without success:

```
dojo.provide("my.FilteringSelect");
dojo.require("dijit.form.FilteringSelect");
dojo.require("dojox.data.QueryReadStore");
dojo.declare(
   "my.FilteringSelect",
   [
      dijit.form.FilteringSelect,  /* base superclass */
      { hasDownArrow:false, storeUrl:"/" }  /* mixin */
   ],
   {
      constructor: function(params, srcNodeRef){
         console.debug("Constructing my.FilteringSelect with storeUrl "
                        + this.storeUrl);
         this.store = new dojox.data.QueryReadStore({url:this.storeUrl});
      }
   }
);
```

Say, I try to generate declaratively in the HTML such a version of `my.FilteringSelect`:

```
<input type="text" id="birthplace" name="birthplace"
       promptMessage="Start typing, and choose among the suggestions"
       storeUrl="/query/regions"
       dojoType="my.FilteringSelect" />
```

This will indeed create a `FilteringSelect` with the desired `promptMessage` (which means that the superclass is properly getting the params), but `hasDownArrow` is `true` (contrary to my default mixin) and the `store` is `null` (and the Firebug console reports that `storeUrl` is "`undefined`").

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops!  I really had things on their head.  I found the right way around. The following works:

```
dojo.provide("my.FilteringSelect");
dojo.require("dijit.form.FilteringSelect");
dojo.require("dojox.data.QueryReadStore");
dojo.declare(
   "my.FilteringSelect",
   dijit.form.FilteringSelect,
   {
      hasDownArrow : false,
      storeUrl : "/",
      constructor: function(params, srcNodeRef){
         dojo.mixin(this, params);
         console.debug("Constructing my.FilteringSelect with storeUrl "
                        + this.storeUrl);
         this.store = new dojox.data.QueryReadStore({url:this.storeUrl});
      }
   }
);
```